# WebBrowser page loading in loop

Tags: c#

Ok, I've been searching for all day to this problem. I have a loop, in which I load webpages and parse them.

The problem is that Application.DoEvents and while cycle reset every variable and counter
Thread.Sleep() affects the thread where web page is loaded
And so does AutoResetEvent.WaitOne

Here's my code

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//some code...
for (int i = 1; i < div.Children.Count; i++)
        {
            webview.Navigate(addr);
            //wait until page is loaded
            html_code.Text += "OK!"; //do further actions
        }
}
```

You notice I have a `for` cycle, so all of methods listed above do not work. I ask you to help me to solve my problem

UPDATE: I've found a solution. It's described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271581/1894634

Comment: do u want just to have the html of this page?

Comment: Actually, yes, but before I need to parse those very loaded pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only html responce, it's better to use `WebClient.DownloadString` or `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync` method

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
//client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
string html_code = client.DownloadString (addr);
```

Comment: Great way to parse pages. Thank you very much

Comment: Well, as it discovered, this method is helpful, but not for me. The error says that I need to be log in.

Comment: depending on the website you can probably use NetworkCredential to login, see my edit.